# Android: after scrolling ListView, onItemClick() calls a false item

Tags: android, listview, scroll

This is my ListView:

[image]

After I scroll this listview, and click for example "Hide", the "Favorite" action gets called (and similar bugs - if I press "Compress", something else gets called).

This only happens AFTER scrolling. Never if I don't scroll the ListView.

This is my Adapter:

```
package com.landa.adapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.example.fileexplorermanager.R;
import com.landa.dialog.OperationsDialogFragment;

public class OperationsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
  private final Context context;
  private final ArrayList<String> data;

  public OperationsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> values) {
    super(context, R.layout.operations_list_item, values);
    this.context = context;
    this.data = values;
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    //View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.operations_list, parent, false);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.operations_list_item, parent, false);

    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.operation_name);

    String temp = data.get(position);
    String op_name = temp;
    textView.setText(op_name);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.operation_image);

    return rowView;

  }
  public int getCount() {
      return data.size();
  }

}
```

This is the dialog (the ListView is inside the Dialog):

```
public class OperationsDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

// operation names
public static final String OP_CUT = "Cut";
public static final String OP_COPY = "Copy";
public static final String OP_RENAME = "Rename";
public static final String OP_DELETE = "Delete";
public static final String OP_SELECT_ALL = "Select all";
public static final String OP_SELECT_INVERSE = "Select inverse";
public static final String OP_CREATE_SHORTCUT = "Create shortcut";
public static final String OP_FAVORITE = "Favorite";
public static final String OP_HIDE = "Hide";
public static final String OP_COMPRESS = "Compress";
public static final String OP_SET_AS_HOME = "Set as home";
public static final String OP_PROPERTIES = "Properties";

ArrayList<String> operationsInfo = new ArrayList<String>();

private OperationsHandler opHandler;
private File f;

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    opHandler = OperationsHandler.getInstance();

    final String operation_type = getArguments().getString("operation_type");
    final String file_absolute_path = getArguments().getString("file_absolute_path");

    if(file_absolute_path != null)
        this.f = new File(file_absolute_path);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    ArrayList<String> operationsList;
    if (operation_type.equals("single_file")) {
        setSingleFileDialogTitle(builder);
        operationsList = getSingleFileOperationsList();
    } else if (operation_type.equals("multiple_files")) {
        setDefaultDialogTitle(builder);
        operationsList = getMultipleFilesOperationsList();
    } else {
        setDefaultDialogTitle(builder);
        operationsList = getDefaultOperationsList();
    }

    OperationsAdapter adap = new OperationsAdapter(getActivity(),
            operationsList);

    // upon operation click, execute operation
    builder.setAdapter(adap, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

            String op_name = getOperationName(((AlertDialog) dialog)
                    .getListView().getChildAt(whichButton));
            if (operation_type.equals("single_file")) {
                executeSingleFileOperation(op_name);
            } else {
                executeMultipleFilesOperation(op_name);
            }
        }
    });

    return builder.create();
}
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: Where is your onClickListener code?

Comment: The ListView lives inside a Dialog, which implements the .onClick(). I posted it right now.

Comment: Hm... upon posting this code I realised that I'm setting the onClick() for the dialog adapter instead of the ListView, might that be my problem?

Comment: Yeah that sounds like the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Implement `onClick` for `ListView` items by getting the `position` of `ListView` item, instead of `Dialog` `OnClick`. I think thats the problem.

Comment: How do I access my ListView outside .setAdapter() method? Inside the method, I got it through the DialogInterface with .getListView(). But outside the .setAdapter()? Perhaps with getActivity().findViewById()?

Comment: Yes...Using getActivity().findViewById(id)

Comment: But what ID does the ListView has? Adapters that create a listview, don't give them an ID... I think I have to get my ListView differently.

Comment: Perhaps I'm supposed to implement builder.setOnItemSelectedListener(listener). I'll give it a try.